# How do I find username that in total uses the most CPU time?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, process, cpu

How do I find username that in total (i.e sum for all processes) uses the most CPU time?

Also I want to find the total amount of memory consumed by running processes of that user and output processes of that user which use `> 50` percent of CPU time.

I don't really know how to parse `ps` in order to be able to maintain the sum for each user.

Comment: If you're on Linux w/ systemd, and have `DefaultCPUAccounting=yes` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, then `systemd-cgtop` should do it. Quite a lot of assumptions, so not really an answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you're after realtime results, without the need to parse `ps`, use top.

`top`

then press

### u

type in the username of the person you want to search, then press *enter*.

Pressing `>` will sort based on a specific column, (in this case you want to keep pressing `>` until you are sorting by %CPU) TIME+ is actual CPU time, not the duration the process has been running. (A common misconception).